# Вывод границ стран + регионов России

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-geocoding-api

Всех приветствую.
Возможно ли через API Яндекс.Карт вывести границы всех стран ('001') и границы регионов России ('RU') одновременно на карту? Почти как здесь https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions/, но чтобы страны (желательно выбранные мной) тоже выделялись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляйте регионы, последовательно вызывая **ymaps.borders.load**, столько, сколько вам требуется.

Регионы России и Турция:

```
ymaps.borders.load('RU').then(function (geojson) {
    var regions = ymaps.geoQuery(geojson);
    regions.addToMap(map);
});

ymaps.borders.load('001', {lang: 'ru', quality: 1}).then(function (geojson) {
    var regions = ymaps.geoQuery(geojson);
    regions.search('properties.iso3166 = "TR"').setOptions('fillColor', '#ff001a').addToMap(map);
});
```

Comment: Ох, насколько все просто оказалось. А я там функцию менял.
Спасибо за помощь!